# Do points revert faster if defenders stand on them?

Tags: team-fortress-2

If a team starts capturing a point but fails to get it converted, it starts reverting back to the team that owns it, making the attacking team lose their progress. If you stand on your point while it's reverting, it will say that that's what it's doing too. Does standing on them while it's reverting speed it up though?

I've gotten conflicting answers about this, and TF2 doesn't really give any indication if it matters.

Does it matter how many people stand on it? Does it work the same way in both Standard Control Point and Attack/Defend Control Point maps?

Comment: I don't think so but I'm scared if I'm wrong I'll be downvoted to oblivion and beyond

Comment: Just one additional note: Though there's no reason to have additional bodies on a point beyond the recap limit for capturing purposes, swarming the point DOES have the advantage of allowing medics to keep everyone overhealed, ensuring a large defense force against incoming threats, and keepign it high if someone should fall...at the cost of splash damage being much easier to deal to everyone, and sneaky spies having more chaos to thrive in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it does, though it varies.  From the wiki:

---

> **Reverting a capture**
>
> When a control point is neutral and both teams are
> trying to capture it, captures can be reverted. If a team begins, but
> does not finish, to capture a neutral point and then is driven off,
> when the other team begins to capture that point, they will first have
> to "revert" the progress that the first team made before they can
> begin to make progress of their own. The revert rate will increase in
> speed with more players of the second team standing on the point.

---

On Attack/Defend maps, points will slowly revert without being affected by the number of players on the point. This is because, in accordance with the definition, the RED team cannot cap the point, whereas BLU is trying to cap the point.  In this way, the point cannot be reverted faster even with additional defenders on the point.  Example:

> **Scene**: Dustbowl
>
> A *BLU scout* quickly rushes towards the cap, and manages to get in
> without anyone noticing him (*a RED demo catches a glimpse of him, but barely enough*).  He almost manages to get the cap fully capped, but to
> his utter dismay, the same *RED Scottish demolitions expert* who spied him turns him
> into flying chunks of meat.
>
> A *RED Pyro*, a *RED scout*, and a *RED Heavy*, noticing this event, tries
> to stand on the point, hoping to revert the changes made by the
> fearsome BLU scout.  Alas, their efforts are in vain, because the cap
> refuses to revert to normal faster, even with more people on the
> point.

---

Whereas, in a 5 CP map, in modes such as KOTH, or even Arena, where a point can be captured by BOTH teams, both RED and BLU, the amount of players on a point can increase the rate of capture as well as the rate of reverting.

> **Scene**: Foundry
>
> A *BLU scout*, not coincidentally the same one mentioned previously,
> eagerly spies the middle capture point, eager to put his team, Builders League United, ahead of the filthy Reliable Excavation Demolition mercenaries.
> He manages to make a heroic effort, getting close
> to capping the point, but his efforts are in vain as a *patriotic
> Russian minigun-toting man* shreds him to pieces.
>
> At this point, the point is nearly capped.  The RED team would not
> like to have the BLU spawns even closer to their base; this would only
> make it harder for them to make a comeback.  A lone *RED spy* jumps on
> the cap, hoping it'll revert.
>
> To his surprise, it does! It seems to move along slightly faster,
> though not as fast.  Signalling for help, the *RED spy*'s prayers
> are answered as a *RED pyro* comes in to spycheck. Coincidentally, the
> revert rate is now 2X, almost double the efforts of a single spy.
> His teammates have all respawned by now, and they all jump on the point. Unfortunately, the point has a max revert limit, darn.  But the point is rapidly reverting, allowing them to safely guard the point and revert it to a possession of theirs........for now.

---

## TL;DR my fanfic:

On Attack/Defend maps, where only one team can capture points, points cannot be reverted faster by defenders.  However, on Standard Control Point maps where both teams are vying to capture points, points can be reverted faster as more defenders stand on the point, up to a cap of 4x on most maps ([more information regarding control point timing here](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Control_point_timing)).

Comment: Your Foundry scene is inaccurate. Reverting capture only applies to unowned points, and the second to last point on both teams is always owned. Your Foundry scenario would work if it was the center point and was at the beginning of the round.

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll revise it

Comment: @MasterSergeantShooterPerson So in other words, uncaptured points will revert their capture time faster, but if your team has already captured the point on a 5cp map, and they're trying to defend it after BLU SCOUT has claimed some time on it, it won't revert to Pure RED faster, no matter how many guys are on it?

Comment: @Zibbobz Correct.

Answer (score 4):

If the capture point is NOT owned (such as at the beginning of KOTH or CP5 maps), then **yes**.

If the capture point IS owned (such as playing attack/defense), then **no**.

You can tell if standing on the point does something by the text on the CP HUD saying "Reverting Capture!"

[Standing on the point DOES prevent attackers from making any progress capping the point though.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTh2_RB8HHI)